# Converting the code written in windows threads to wxwidgets threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi, thread-safety, wxwidgets

I have the code that makes use of multithreading however it is via using windows i want to convert the code in wxwdigets i have been trying for a long time but there is no success and ultimately i deleted what i did and wants to start from scratch

```
#include "windows.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>


DWORD WINAPI ThreadFn(LPVOID vpParam);

int main() {
    using namespace std;

    // Create the thread and pass in the function pointer and counter
    unsigned int uiCounter = 0;
    DWORD qThreadID;
    HANDLE hThread = CreateThread(0, 0, ThreadFn, &uiCounter, 0, &qThreadID);

    // Loop until the user enters 'q'
    char cChar = ' ';
    while (cChar != 'q') {
        cout << uiCounter << endl;
        cChar = (char)getchar();
    }

    // Close the handle to the thread
    CloseHandle(hThread);

    return 0;
}


DWORD WINAPI ThreadFn(LPVOID vpParam)
{
    unsigned int& uirCounter = *((unsigned int*)vpParam);
    // Increment up to the maximum value
    while (uirCounter < 0xFFFFFFFF) {
        ++uirCounter;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is there a specific question here?

Comment: Yes i want to do the same code in wxwidgets i did try something it kept on crashing so i deleted it out of frustration , i need to build everything from a scratch so need suggestions/possibleanswers

Comment: You do understand that wxWidgets is simply a cross-platform GUI toolkit? If you're targeting other platforms, you will have to find other options for threading. For example, OS X now offers the GCD, you've got the more low-level POSIX-standardized threads (on OS X, BSD, Linux distros - with a bit of effort - even on Windows) or even the new developments with C++11 which include threading facilities.

Comment: I am not targetting anything else than windows , those are a good thing to work on however i need to wxwidgets threads for this stuff.

Comment: http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/overview_thread.html
http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/group__group__class__threading.html

Perhaps this will help you enable cooperation with the native threading approach.

Comment: @DomagojPandža wxWidgets is not "simply a cross-platform GUI toolkit", its scope goes beyond GUI. If one is using wxWidgets already, it makes sense to use threads offered by wx.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of serious problems with the code you have posted.  They need to be fixed before you do anything more.

1. The worker thread is a 'busy loop'.  It will consume all the available CPU cycles and make anything else, such as running a GUI, impossible slow and unresponsive.  I suggest adding a call to Sleep() into the while loop, as a quick fix.
2. Both the main thread and the worker thread attempt to access the counter variable simultaneously.  You run this long enough and it will crash.  You should protect the counter with a mutex or equivalent.

Let's do a slight redesign, and port to wxWidgets.  We will need

A.  A worker thread which increments a counter ten times a second ( approximately ) and sleeps for the rest of the time so we can update the GUI

B.  A GUI thread which checks and displays the counter value twice per second

C.  The GUI thread will also monitor the keyboard and stop the counter if 'q' is pressed.

D.  We will use the [wxThreadHelper](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/2.9.4/classwx_thread_helper.html) class to manage our threads.

The key implementation details are as follows

Define the main frame, including all the wxThreadHelper goodness

```
class MyFrame : public wxFrame, public wxThreadHelper
{
public:
    MyFrame(const wxString& title);

    // worker thread entry point
    wxThread::ExitCode Entry();

    // keyboard monitor
    void OnChar(wxKeyEvent& event );

    // display updater
    void OnTimer(wxTimerEvent& event);

private:

    // the counter
    unsigned int mCounter;

    // protect the counter from access by both threads at once
    wxCriticalSection mCS;

    // display update timer
    wxTimer * mTimer;

    DECLARE_EVENT_TABLE()
};
```

Watch out for keyboard and timer events

```
BEGIN_EVENT_TABLE(MyFrame, wxFrame)
    EVT_CHAR(MyFrame::OnChar)
    EVT_TIMER(-1,MyFrame::OnTimer)
END_EVENT_TABLE()
```

Construct the frame

```
MyFrame::MyFrame(const wxString& title)
       : wxFrame(NULL, wxID_ANY, title)
       , mCounter( 0 )
{
    // set the frame icon
    SetIcon(wxICON(sample));


    CreateStatusBar(2);
    SetStatusText("Welcome to Asynchronous Counter!");

    // Create thread and start it going

    CreateThread();
    GetThread()->Run();

   // Create update timer and start it going

    mTimer = new wxTimer(this);
    mTimer->Start(500);
}
```

Worker thread increments counter 10 times per second

```
 wxThread::ExitCode MyFrame::Entry()
 {
     // loop, so long as we haven't been asked to quit
    while ( ! GetThread()->TestDestroy()) {
        {
            // increment counter, to a maximum value
             wxCriticalSectionLocker lock( mCS );
             if( mCounter >= 0xFFFFFFFF )
                 break;
            ++mCounter;
        }

        // Let other things happen for 1/10 second
        Sleep(100);

    }

    // Counter is finished, or we have been asked to stop
    return (wxThread::ExitCode)0;

 }
```

Monitor keyboard for quit request

```
 void MyFrame::OnChar(wxKeyEvent& event )
    {
        event.Skip();
        if( event.GetKeyCode() == (int) 'q' )
            GetThread()->Delete();
    }
```

Update the display when timer fires

```
void MyFrame::OnTimer(wxTimerEvent& )
{
    unsigned int current_counter_value;
    {
         wxCriticalSectionLocker lock( mCS );
        current_counter_value = mCounter;
    }
    SetStatusText(wxString::Format("Counter = %d",current_counter_value));
}
```